# How do I use InputType=numberDecimal with the "phone" soft keypad?

Tags: android, numeric-keypad

For an `EditText` box, the user should only be entering valid numbers, so I am using `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`. Unfortunately, the soft keyboard that Android brings up has numbers only along the top row, while the next three rows have various other symbols (dollar sign, percent sign, exclamation mark, space, etc). Since the `numberDecimal` only accepts numbers 0-9, negative sign, and decimal point, it would make more sense to use the "phone" soft keyboard (0-9 in a 3x3 grid, plus some other symbols). This would make the buttons larger and easier to hit (since it's a 4x4 grid rather than a 10x4 grid in the same screen area). Unfortunately, using `android:inputType="phone"` allows non-numeric characters such as parentheses

I have attempted to use `android:inputType="numberDecimal|phone"`, but the `numberDecimal` aspect of the bit flag seems to be ignored. I have also tried using `android:inputType="phone"` in combination with `android:digits="0123456789-."`, but that still allows multiple negative signs or decimal points (`inputType="number"` has really good error checking for things like that, and won't let the user even type it in). I have also tried using `android:inputType="phone"` in the xml layout file, while using a `DigitsKeyListener` in the java code, but then that just uses the default number soft keyboard (the one that has numbers only along top row) (it appears to set `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`, which voids the `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE` set by the xml layout).

Writing a custom IME wouldn't work, since the user would have to select the IME as a global option outside the app.

Is there any way to use the "phone" style soft keyboard while also using the "number" restrictions on what is entered?

Comment: On Android 4, InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER gives a nice 4x4 keypad, and is slightly better than InputType.Type_CLASS_PHONE for plain numbers. Unfortunately they screwed it up on the older versions, forcing us developers to hack it ourselves.

Comment: I had the need to support numbers and decimal points for an edit box.  I tried the below and it seems to show numeric key pad with numbers and period.

amountField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So far, what I've decided to do is extend the DigitsKeyListener and override getInputType() so that it will return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE. This allows me to use the handy filter() in DigitsKeyListener, but at the same time use the TYPE_CLASS_PHONE soft keyboard. I'm new to Android programming, but this appears to work without breaking anything. Code is something like this:

```
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.text.InputType;
public class CustomDigitsKeyListener extends DigitsKeyListener
{
    public CustomDigitsKeyListener() {
        super(false, false);
    }

    public CustomDigitsKeyListener(boolean sign, boolean decimal) {
        super(sign, decimal);
    }

    public int getInputType() {
        return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE;
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in doing this (switching the return of getInputType() to something that the superclass didn't intend)?

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem. This works for me:

```
<item name="android:inputType">numberDecimal</item>
<item name="android:digits">0123456789.</item>
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Adam Dunn code works perfect, but didnt show how to implement the class

```
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.text.InputType;
public class CustomDigitsKeyListener extends DigitsKeyListener
{
    public CustomDigitsKeyListener() {
        super(false, false);
    }

    public CustomDigitsKeyListener(boolean sign, boolean decimal) {
        super(sign, decimal);
    }

    public int getInputType() {
        return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE;
    }
}
```

then you have to instance like this

```
MyTextView.setKeyListener(new CustomDigitsKeyListener(true,true));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
android:inputType="phone"
android:digits="0123456789."
```

Add this to your `EditText` xml layout. 
This will show phone layout, but only allow user to tap digits specified. 
User tapping other characters will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:numeric="integer"` in your EditText view.

Comment: android:numeric has be deprecated. I tried it out anyways, and it still presents the more-full keyboard with dollar sign, percent sign, exclamation mark, space, etc.