# Android - Numeric (float) soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I need to insert in an EditText some numeric data with decimal. I know that i could insert this:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

in my xml file. But I'd like a different keyboard with only numeric (and point) keys. Something like the "phone" keyboard (`android:inputType="phone"`).
I know, this is a duplicated question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830664/how-do-i-use-inputtype-numberdecimal-with-the-phone-soft-keypad) the original) but i decided to open a new one because the first one doesn't look to have a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on keyboard app, which is installed on your device, which buttons are visible for different inputTypes. You can't simply override default keyboard due to security issues. But you can create your own implementation. But it needs to be registered by user in settings.

There is how to do it:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html

And sample keyboard:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html